# Can I add a Pass to the Wallet?

Tags: ios, passbook, wallet

I want to add a pass to the user's wallet.

I've had a difficult time finding straight forward documentation on this topic, and would appreciate any and all advice.

Comment: Well, you will need to create a pass package.. its kind of a lot of steps.. Here is a helpful tutorial for setting this up: https://www.raywenderlich.com/20734/beginning-passbook-part-1

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I believe I've already created the pass package (partially using the tutorial you linked). What I think I need to do next now that I have already created a pass package is link the pass package with the app and wallet.

Comment: The code is incredibly simple so it is hard to believe you have actually tried to code this yourself. Either embed the .pkpass bundle in your app bundle or retrieve it from your server then use the PKAddPassesViewController method to present the pass to the user.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKAddPassesViewController_Ref/

Comment: I love code that is incredibly simple. Thank you!

Comment: @PassKit Can you link documentation for storing and retrieving a Pass to and from a server? I've been unable to find anything useful. Thank you

Comment: Seriously? http://wt.is/8m

Comment: Ha! Yes, seriously. I've been digging for days and can't find anything useful.

Comment: I found this link to be a clear and concise starting point: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_passkit/

Comment: @PassKit How to let the app create a unique pass for each user with his name on it? The docs focused mainly on downloading passes from servers, which is not the case.